# Ember Simple Auth Devise giving error 'Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined' Rails 4 backend

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, devise

I'm using Ember.SimpleAuth and the package for devise. I've used devise and rails numerous times before but I am pretty new to ember. Also, I'm beginning to wonder if I should ditch devise for Ember apps with token authentication...Anyway here is my code.

**UPDATE**

2 Specific things I noticed:

1. I've cleaned up my assets and am using the latest ember-simple-auth.js. I don't seem to have an authenticatorFactory because the following line is 'undefined' inside the 'var Session' definition:

   ```
   _this.container.lookup(authenticatorFactory)
   ```
2. I feel like I should be calling the authenticate method that is in the ember-simple-auth-devise.js, but that file never gets touched according to my console. Is that the way it should be?

**END UPDATE**

---

I'm pretty sure I followed the directions correctly:

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
//= require quiz
//= require pen
//= require ember-simple-auth
//= require ember-simple-auth-devise
//= require_self
//= require quizzmob
Quizzmob = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
```

initializers/authentication.js.coffee

```
Ember.Application.initializer
  name: "authentication"
  initialize: (container, application) ->
    Ember.SimpleAuth.setup container, application,
      authorizerFactory: 'ember-simple-auth-authorizer:devise'
```

I have a route defined for login:

```
@route "login"
```

And a controller:

```
Quizzmob.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.SimpleAuth.LoginControllerMixin,
    authenticatorFactory: "ember-simple-auth-authenticator:devise"
)
```

And my login form:

```
<form {{action 'authenticate' on='submit'}}>
  <label for="identification">Login</label>
    {{input id='identification' placeholder='Enter Login' value=identification}}
  <label for="password">Password</label>
    {{input id='password' placeholder='Enter Password' type='password' value=password}}
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

The error I get says: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined"
It is called on the authenticate method in ember-simple-auth.js, in the following location:

```
return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    _this.container.lookup(authenticatorFactory)|.authenticate(options).then(function(content) {
                                                ^
```

There is absolutely no request sent to the server, so I think there's something wrong with my ember setup.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error with Ember CLI, I added to the Brocfile.js this:

```
app.import('vendor/ember-simple-auth/ember-simple-auth.js');                     
app.import('vendor/ember-simple-auth/ember-simple-auth-devise.js');
```

Save and **restart** the server.

```
ember server
```

So, make sure you are including `ember-simple-auth-devise.js` and that you are restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

The authenticator is registered as `ember-simple-auth-authenticator:devise`,  not `ember-simple-auth-authenticators:devise` (without the 's').

Comment: sorry, I actually had it without the 's' at first, but was getting the same error. I changed it just as an experiment after looking through the source for a bit. Thanks so much for your response though. I'll change that back right now.

Comment: I added an update that might help you diagnose my problem a little easier.

Comment: did you make sure you have the latest versions o ember-simple-auth AND ember-simple-auth-devise?

Comment: Yes I did. The ember-simple-auth-rails-demo (https://github.com/ugisozols/ember-simple-auth-rails-demo) worked for me. I'm not sure if there's an issue in the ember-simple-auth devise package, or if there is an issue on my end with my setup/gemfile/bower/other dependencies etc. I haven't yet tried using devise along with the ember-simple-auth-rails-demo, but I'll let you know how that goes when I try.

Comment: Can you debug a bit and make sure the devise extension's initializer is actually called: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth-component/blob/master/ember-simple-auth-devise.js#L250

Answer (score 0):

Create a `login.js` controller, `ember g controller login` and add the authenticate code there...

/controller/login.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
  authenticator: 'simple-auth-authenticator:devise'
});
```